# Is there a way to check if a variable is defined in Java?

Tags: java, android, variables

In my app in android I need to check if a variable has been defined yet so I dont get a null pointer exception.  Any way around this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The code won't compile if you try to use an undefined variable, because, In Java, variables must be defined before they are used.

But note that variables can be null, and it is possible to check if one is null to avoid `NullPointerException`:

```
if (var != null) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I guess you mixed Javascript and Java. Javascript is dynamic, interpreted where the code does not go through compilation. So, in JS it quite makes sense to check it.

Comment: @Chartle  This is correct.  In java land we use the terminology declare and initialize.  `Foo var;` is the declaration.  `var = new Foo();` is the initialization of var.  We are instantiating an instance of Foo.  Worth reading up on the terms to help understand others questions.

Comment: Yeah Im just trying to check if a variable is empty.  Im doing this on android and in my OnCreate() I and initializing it as an empty array with two slots and in my onResume() I check to see if it is still empty and Im getting NullPointers.  Tried throwing them but still nothing

Comment: Never mind I got it. Just threw in one of the old try/catch blocks;

Answer (score 3):

```
if (variableName != null)
{
//Do something if the variable is declared.        
}
else
{
//Do something if the variable doesn't have a value        
}
```

I think that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

It will throw an exception if we try to use an undefined variable in java. To over come these make use of wrapper Class and assigned it to null.

```
Integer a = null; //correct
int a = null;//error
```